# Best way to create a vpn between two windows machines?

Tags: windows, vpn, local-area-network

I'm looking for way to create a VPN between two windows machines. I want the installed software to behave as if the two computers are connected through a LAN.

What's the best (free) way to do it?

Thanks,

Udi

Comment: What operating system are the PCs running?

Comment: XP and Vista, but I'm looking for a general solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[openvpn](https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/) - free & open source. works fine not only under linux but also for [windows](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/install.html?start=1).

*To note the opensource/community edition is [free](https://openvpn.net/faq/what-are-the-main-differences-between-openvpn-open-source-and-openvpn-access-server/), there is a commercial version too.*

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Windows machines, client OSs can accept up to 10 incoming PPTP VPN connections (EDIT: only in the Professional or Business editions of Windows accept up to 10 connections; Home editions only accept 1 incoming connection) as per [these instructions](http://www.onecomputerguy.com/networking/xp_vpn_server.htm). Of course, Windows has built-in PPTP VPN client capabilities so there is no software needed. You'll need to edit the router that the receiving computer is behind to forward [PPTP ports](http://www.google.com/search?q=pptp+port) to the newly created VPN "server". The real question is: does the router that the receiving computer is behind [pass GRE through](http://www.google.com/search?q=gre+passthrough)?

Comment: While I'm typically a proponent of Hamachi for this sort of thing... I have to thank you for that link. That was very informative and something I wasn't even aware of being in XP.

Comment: It's also in Vista as well. I assume 2k can do it, but can't confirm that at the moment. What's more surprising is that apparently the home editions can do this as well, albeit only one at a time (XP Home only allows one incoming connection at a time and I assume the same for Vista home). The professional / business editions allow 10 incoming connections.

Answer (score 6):

Hamachi (http://hamachi.cc/download) provides a very easy setup for a VPN, after setting up your server, you'll just need to configure your router to open up the applicable ports.

Check out http://www.itsatechworld.com/2006/01/17/hamachi-vpn-solution/ for a quick setup guide.

Comment: I love and fully recommend Hamachi- easy to set up, easy to use, easy to stop using if that time ever comes. It's like setting up an instant messenger.